# SwiftUI, CoreData - not accepting custom %K NSPredicate

Tags: swiftui

```
init(key: String = "", filters: [FilterModel]){
        var filterPredicates: [NSPredicate] = []
        
        if !key.isEmpty {
            for filter in filters {
                if filter.active{
                    filterPredicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", filter.key, key))
                }
            }
            
            _foundResults = FetchRequest<Offense>(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)], predicate: NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: filterPredicates))
        }
 
        searchKey = key
    }
```

ERROR: `"unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (description CONTAINS[cd] \"T\")"`

Hi, I don't really know what else to do.

Thank you very much for any idea.

I've tried using `format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", key` - that worked.
No idea why the other doesn't.

Comment: filter.key: String
key: String

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have mistaken one path key name with the other, so it couldn't find the "description", 'cause it doesn't exist.............. :))

Sorry.